# What is the difference between Number.isFinite() and Number.isInteger() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I can't seem to find a difference in results when using `Number.isFinite()` and `Number.isInteger()`. I get that finite means not infinity, but `Number.isInteger(Infinity)` returns `false` too, so when do these two methods actually differ in their results?

Comparing the outcomes for all these values and they produce the same results, so I'm stumped as to why both methods exist:

```
[0, 1, -1, '1', Infinity, -Infinity, NaN, true, false, {}, null, undefined].forEach(val => {
  const string = typeof val === 'string' ? `"${val}"` : val === null ? `null` : typeof val === 'object' ? `{}` : val; 
  console.log(`Number.isFinite(${string}): ${Number.isFinite(val)}`)
  console.log(`Number.isInteger(${string}): ${Number.isInteger(val)}`) 
})
```

Comment: The "infinity" concept only applies to floating point values.  There is no infinite value for integers, so the two would always return the same.

Comment: Add the number 3.14 to your list (or any other decimal number) - Number.isFinite(3.14): true, Number.isInteger(3.14): false

Comment: @TimRoberts "*There is no infinite value for integers*" news to me. What would be the last integer beyond which there are no more integers?

Comment: Why would you expect `Infinity` to be an integer? I mean, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @VLAZ -- We are talking about computers here.  The integers roll around.  One past the largest positive is the largest negative.  There is no value you can put in an integer computer register that means "infinity".

Answer (score 0):

The difference is decimals. Finite includes decimals, integer does not:

```js
Number.isFinite(1.1) // true
Number.isInteger(1.1) // false
```

I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of those when testing. Thanks @Tim Roberts!